# R: convert character into vector with one column and with number of rows the same as the number of words in character

Tags: r, vector, character

I'd like to know if it is possible to create a vector with only one column and number of rows being the same as the number of words in an input character string.
As an example, for the character string

```
> topicsLists 
[1] "nice"       "experience"
```

I would like to have a vector like:

```
[1] "nice"      
[2] "experience"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you mean like `matrix(topicsLists)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors don't have columns.  But what you could do is create a single column `matrix`

```
> topicsLists <- c("nice", "experience")
> as.matrix(topicsLists)
#      [,1]        
# [1,] "nice"      
# [2,] "experience"
```

Or you could also do `matrix(topicsLists)` for the same result.